# Minecraft Forge add sound programmatically

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

How can i register sound effects programmatically in Minecraft Forge (1.7.10)?
The only way i know how to add sounds is create *sounds.json* in mod jar file and list all needed sounds there.

I've wrote Minecraft mod that loading resources dynamically from binary files. I made texture loading, model loading, but how should i load sounds from *ByteArrayInputStream* or something like that?

```
count = input.readInt();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    input.readByte();
    String name = readString(input);
    input.readByte();
    int size = input.readInt();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    input.read(buffer, 0, size);
    /*
    try {
        configurable.models.add(new OptimizedModel(new WavefrontObject(name, new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer))));
        // code from model loader
    } catch (ModelFormatException e) {
                    System.exit(0);
    }*/
    input.readByte();
}
```

Comment: Do you already have some kind of code template with which we can start with?

Comment: @Zabuza I mean, is there a function that accepts buffer with ogg sound data? I added some code